# How to set file field upload path to Taxonomy term url?

Tags: tokens

I have `article` content type and it has `field_pdf` field and `field_categury` fields.
`field_categury` is a taxonomy term reference field.
I use `File (Field) Paths` module and I want to set `field_file` path to `field_categury` term url.
I try to use Field tokens but i can not set it.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution:
I should use entity token module and use this token in file path:

```
[node:field-categury:0:url:relative]
```

Comment: maybe [term:parent:parent:url:absolute] 
list at https://www.drupal.org/node/390482#drupal7tokenslist-token-term